# Ceiling fan trouble/question

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I have been working with a ceiling fan for the last few days and I feel utterly defeated.

The fan in question is the Clarkston 2 44in. LED.

I went into the previous light fixture and disassembled it. Here's where I found it odd. There were 4 wires, 2 feeding into 2 individual light bulb fixtures. 1 black and 1 white feeding into each. Cut those 4 wires to completely pull the fixture off and then stripped them a little bit.

The fan I'm working with has 3 wires. 1 white, 1 black, and 1 blue.

My initial thought was to connect the 2 black wires to the 1 black and 1 blue from the fan together with a pigtail. Combine those 4 and then the 2 whites to the 1 from the fan in a separate pigtail.

So 2 black wires on 1 black and 1 blue. 2 whites to the 1 white. I didn't use any of the ground wires. Nothing seems to have worked.

Asked my father who does some electric work at work but he couldn't figure it out either as it is not his specialty. He recommended I turn the switch on and touch some of the bare wires to see if anything turns on. Nothing. Absolutely nothing.

And help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Were the original 2 lights on 1 switch or on 2 switches?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved?

Comment: These pictures ok?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box that controls this fan location?

Comment: Pictures are very shotty.

Comment: Can you get a shot looking squarely into the back of the switch box?

Comment: I can't tell if they are both black or if there is one black and one white. Took some of the dust off and it looks like they are both black